# launching the xml files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Below hrcmd.cmd file

echo off

for /F %%a in ("%~fs0") do set THIS_DIR=%%~dpa

call %THIS_DIR%FRSetenv.cmd

set CLASSPATH=

set ANT_HOME=

set ANT_HOME=%HYPERION_ANT%

set JAVA_HOME=

set JAVA_HOME=%HYPERION_JRE%

set PATH_ORIG=%PATH%

set PATH=

set PATH=%FR_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\BIN;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%PATH_ORIG%

if not exist "%FR_HOME%\temp" mkdir "%FR_HOME%\temp"

set ANT_OPTS=-Djava.io.tmpdir="%FR_HOME%\temp" -Xms128m -Xmx256m

Below Batchadmin.xml file

echo on

Allows running of batches and encoding passwords.

```
<!-- set global properties for this build -->
```

resultproperty="batch.return">

path="${home.hyperion}/products/financialreporting/lib/FRBaseCP.jar"/>

Djava.util.logging.config.class=oracle.core.ojdl.logging.LoggingConfiguration" />

Doracle.core.ojdl.logging.config.file=${home.hyperion}/products/financialreporting/bin/Batc

hAdminlogging.xml" />

${env.PASSWORD}" />

${env.BATCH_INPUT_FILENAME}">

${env.BATCH_INPUT_FILENAME} - See logs for details">

${env.BATCH_INPUT_FILENAME} - See logs for details">

```
<target name="batch.encodepassword">
```

path="${home.hyperion}/products/financialreporting/lib/FRBaseCP.jar"/>

script below

@ECHO OFF

set userid=xxx

set pwd=xxx

SET "xml_dir=c:\Today\set"

SET "hyp_server=10.11.12.13"

For %%z in ("%xml_dir%*.xml") do (

call scheduleBatch "%%z" %userid% %pwd% %hyp_server%

echo %errorlevel%

if %errorlevel% == 1    >>"C:\Today\xml-error.log" echo "%%z" failed

if not %errorlevel% == 1 >>"C:\Today\xml-pass.log" echo "%%z" succeeded

)

I need to create a generic batch script to launch the batch xml files from a folders and scheduling through windows task sheduler at predefined time.
These batch xml files are from financial reporting studio and scheduleBatch.cmd is the inbuilt utility which calls these xml files when we run script. Below  batch script I have written a genric script(which launch a set of batch .xml files from any folder and scheduling it through windows task scheduler at a predefined time to run particular folder).

```
REM Use this to schedule a Financial Reporting Batch from a command line
REM Specify four arguments when calling this command file:
REM The first is the fully qualified name of the batch input xml file for the batch to be scheduled such as c:\\temp\\mybatch.xml
REM The second is the Reports Web Server URL with correct protocol and port such as http:/XXX
REM The third is a valid username for the batch routine
REM The fourth is the password
SETLOCAL
if "%~1" == "" goto Usage
if "%~2" == "" goto Usage
if "%~3" == "" goto Usage
if "%~4" == "" goto Usage
if not exist "%~1" goto NotExist
SET BATCH_INPUT_FILENAME=%~fs1
SET WEB_SERVER=%2
SET USERNAME=%3
SET PASSWORD=%4
for /F %%a in ("%~fs0") do set THIS_DIR=%%~dpa
call %THIS_DIR%hrcmd.cmd
ant -q -f "%FR_HOME%\bin\BatchAdmin.xml" batch.schedule
goto End
:Usage
ECHO Usage: BatchInputFilename FRWebServerURL Username Password
goto End
:NotExist
ECHO File "%~1" not found
:End
ENDLOCAL
```

2   @ECHO OFF

set "userid=joe"

set "pwd=jack"

SET "xml_dir=c:\Today\set"

SET "FILE=%MAINLOG%"

SET "hyp_server=10.11.12.13"

For %%z in ("%xml_dir%*.xml") do (

call scheduleBatch "%%z" %userid% %pwd% %hyp_server%

findstr /R "\ ErrCheck

for /F %%A in ("ErrCheck") do If %%~zA NEQ 0 (

echo  Error in Batch scheduling Process......................... >> %MAINLOG%

copy %MAINLOG% %LOG_DIR%\%MAINLOG%-Error.log

DEL /Q ErrCheck
)

else (

echo  Batch scheduling Process was successfull......................... >> %MAINLOG%

copy %MAINLOG% %LOG_DIR%\%MAINLOG%-Pass.log

)

)

Comment: This is your second post concerning this topic, and until now it is not clear (for me), what you need. 1) where is the `file list` ? 2) what for `parameters`  do you mean 3) how should the `log file` handle errors ?  Your question is **not** a real one and should be closed!

Answer (score 1):

This calls schedulebatch.cmd with every *.xml file in a directory and with your extra settings.  The log files depend on your schedulebatch.cmd returning an appropriate errorlevel.

```
@ECHO OFF
set userid=joe
set pwd=jackson
SET "xml_dir=c:\today\set"
SET "hyp_server=10.11.12.13"
For %%z in ("%xml_dir%\*.xml") do (
call schedulebatch "%%z" %userid% %pwd% %hyp_server%
if errorlevel 1    >>"C:\Today\xml-error.log" echo "%%z" failed
if not errorlevel 1 >>"C:\Today\xml-pass.log" echo "%%z" succeeded
)
```

Comment: Thankyou for understandin and answering my quest.I have a req where we have set of batch xml files in C:\Today\set folder and I need to execute these xml files using batch script and if these files execute successfuly goes to success.log file if they are failed then will go to error.log file and scheduleBatch.cmd is inbuit utility file which executes these xml file.Please help me out how to design the code with this req.I really appreciate your help and Thanks in advance

Comment: I really appreciate your help when I run the above it says "1 was unexpected at this time" and it is not launching the xml files do I need to add something..Please help me out.....Thanks in advance

Comment: In C:\Today\set folder I have a.xml,b.xml.c.txt when I run the below script it is launching a.xml b.xml.The c.txt shud go to xml-error.log file and a.xml and b.xml to xml-pass.log butI don't see any errors and success in that respective files

Comment: I really appreciate your time and patience.I executed the script and it is executing xml files:) and I have a.xml b.xml c.txt in set folder so a.xml,b.xml-->xml-pass.log and c.txt->xml-error.log but in xml-error.log I see a.xml and b.xml files and in xml-pass.log I donot see anything Please help me out to achieve this

Comment: Your schedulebatch.cmd has to return an errorlevel of zero to pass and one or higher to fail.  There is no other information of where to derive pass or fail information from.

Comment: Above I have added scheduleBatch.cmd utilty let me know whether this Information will suffice to acheve this and also I have added some script In which the output that is piping to a file  
So whatever the error level is it all go to your output folder. can we peform something like a find string (Error).Please let if this script looks good or do I need to stick with previous script that you provided me to make it work. Please check and help me out

Comment: schedulebatch.cmd has to return the exit code.  Does it do so?  Can we see that batch file?

Comment: I have added the batch xml file Please check and let me know

Comment: I didn't ask for the .xml file - that is of no use.

Comment: In the script I need  to call multiple batch XML files in a single batch(.bat)file I first exported the Batch for command line scheduling, which generates an XML file. In my case, I stored the XML file in "F:\Oracle\Middleware\EPMSystem11R1\products\ Financial Reporting \bin\" Above I have added scheduleBatch.cmd utilty file which call these xml files and please let me know which batch file you are refering to?

Comment: scheduleBatch.cmd is not complete and I can only assume that ant returns errorlevels.   Did you try the code I put in my answer?  Did it have anything in the log files?

Comment: I have modiefied the script and its working nw and going to success log file.I really appreciate your time and help. In my script I have hardcoded the username pwd servername and xml_dir Please let me know how to pass the parameters and call these parameters in my script so that when user input like xxx.bat foldername un pwd servername they should have unique userId pwd and should run on any server and foldername(which has xmlfiles).Please let me know how to achieve this and also I have added batchadmin.xml and hrcmd files which is called in ScheduleBatch.cmd.

Comment: can you please provide me your email so that I can email you all the information clearly